# Manual Slide cookie Expiration Blazor Server Side

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, blazor, blazor-server-side

is it possible to manually extend cookie authentication expiration? This is my configuration for cookie:

```
 .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                    options.Cookie.Name = "__Host-.AspNetCore.Session";
                })
```

However, I would like to create functionality that will be shown to the user a few minutes before it expires with a button that will extend this time.